# Does the $\infty$-groupoid functor $\Pi$ commute with pushouts of nice spaces?

Tags: homotopy-theory, groupoids

Given a pushout diagram of nice topological spaces (such as CW complexes), does the infinity groupoid functor $\Pi(-)$ commute with the pushout? More precisely, does the pushout diagram get sent to a homotopy pushout?

Comment: No: squares of top spaces that are sent to pushouts by Π are called homotopy pushouts. Not all pushouts are homotopy pushouts, no matter how nice the spaces are...

Comment: A sufficient condition is that both maps are open embeddings, or that one of them is a relative CW complex. As far as I know there is no simple characterization of homotopy pushouts.

Comment: Okay cool, this works for the example I was thinking about: attaching a 2-cell to a torus by the inclusion of a circle homotopic whose attaching map is homotopic to a point. This would give the fundamental groupoid $\Pi(X) \cong \Pi(S^2 \vee (S^1 \times S^1))$

Comment: You can even cook up plenty of counterexamples using just discrete spaces with finitely many points. Probably the simplest example is the pushout of the map from a two-point space to a one-point space along itself. The pushout is again just a one-point space, while the homotopy pushout is $S^1$: you get it by taking two copies of the one-point space and identifying them in *two* ways, resulting in two arcs.